How to perform convolution using a specified method in pytorch?
Any experts familiar with PyTorch source code? I'm looking to extract the process of invoking specific convolution methods from MKL and cuDNN in PyTorch to create custom operators. How should I go about this？
I've developed a convolution operator using col2im+gemm and I want to compare its efficiency with the convolutions implemented in PyTorch using the high-performance libraries MKL/cuDNN. However, due to PyTorch's complex dispatch mechanism, it's difficult to manually control it to only use the col2im+gemm method for convolution; it automatically selects the optimal implementation.
So, I thought about extracting the process by which PyTorch calls specific high-performance operators and turning it into a custom operator. This way, when comparing, there won't be any uncertainty about which operator PyTorch is using.
However, I'm facing difficulties in actually finding this calling process. PyTorch operator implementations are too complex, and I'm struggling to understand how to locate the corresponding operator implementation code and wrap it into a custom operator.
I've attempted to read through the source code and found the operator description file native_functions.yaml, as well as PyTorch's slower self-implemented methods. However, I haven't yet found the code related to calling the high-performance neural network operator libraries

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
